# ListBox ItemsSource

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am doing my first Windows Phone 7 application. It looks like DataGrid is not supported there. I am trying to find work around.

I do have such ListBox:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="myListBox" Grid.Row="3">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Name="assetImage" Grid.Column="0" />
                    <TextBlock Name="assetId" Grid.Column="1" />
                    <TextBlock Name="market" Grid.Column="2" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

How do I set ItemsSource for such kind of list?

Let's say I have `List<MyObject> { string uri; string assetid; string market;}`

Thanks!

Comment: How is setting an ItemsSource a problem? (Also your DataTemplate lacks bindings)

Comment: @H.B, I am asking for help here. Instead of posting spam, you could write a code.

Comment: @WildGoat You'd set the ItemsSource the same way you would set any property - either with a binding or code behind. `myListBox.ItemsSource = MyList;` or `<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" ... />`

Comment: @Rachel, but how does it know which Column to which property it has to assign? Say, `myListBox.ItemsSource = MyList; where MyList = { string, string, string } ` How does it know what it should assign to first string as assetImage, second as assetId and third as market?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this (adding bindings in your elements):

```
<ListBox x:Name="myListBox" Grid.Row="3">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="{Binding uri}" Name="assetImage" Grid.Column="0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding assetid}"  Name="assetId" Grid.Column="1" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding market}" Name="market" Grid.Column="2" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Now add the following code at the point where you want to create binding:

```
myListBox.ItemsSource=myObjects;
```

I assume that `MyObject` is a class with `uri`, `assetid` and `market` as properties and `myObjects` is a `List<>` with items of the type `MyObject`.